# appending the input json in a log file for each iteration

Tags: python, logging

I have test casep which will run for multiple iterations with different test data each time. For each run, the input json file is different. Now say for example, I have 10 set of data and out of 10, 2 got failed and as a result I am getting status code <> 200 fot those 2 cases. For these 2 cases, I want to append the input json file in a separate log file. Following is the code I have used but it is working when there is only one fail case. If the fail cases > 1, its not appending the second one. The code I have used is below'

```
if statuscode != 200:
    json_data = context.payload
    sys.stdout = open("1AP.log", "w")
    print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=2))
    sys.stdout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use append mode like this: `open("1AP.log", "a")`.

When we open the file in write mode, it automatically removes all the contents from the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot..It worked as per your suggestion